# Vim - Cannot reenter Vim after executing gcc inside Vim

Tags: vim

I am having an really annoying issue with Vim. I am learning C and everytime I invoke `:!gcc something.c -o something`, Vim would exit to shell outputting whatever gcc outputs. However, from here, I cannot go back to Vim. If I press ctrl-D or type exit, the terminal just says "Stopped vim something.c". However, now when I try to type "Vim something.c" again, Vim would give an error saying the file is in swap or something and that it is already opened in another session.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Type `fg` in the shell. But the problem you have is that you probably changed the shell line in vim. What is the value of `verbose set shell?`. If you started an interactive shell you will most likely have problems

Comment: Yes to 'verbose set shell' - but also what is your operating system?  This is not the standard behavior of vim, I just tried your issue and had no problems.  And what does "I cannot go back to Vim" mean to you?  What does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a makefile to help you compile and report back your errors to vim. You can do this in C and C++.

You will make a file called 'makefile' in the same dir as the file you are making. You can execute that file in vim or in the terminal and it will act the same.

You call the makefile by typing in 'make' and ':make' in vim.

More documentation
https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html#C